# OData Olingo $Filter

Tags: odata, olingo

I created a app using OData JPA feature.

This works fine with following URL's:

```
http://localhost:19080/jpa2/Employee.svc/ALERTSs
```

Now I want to use the filter with following URL:

```
http://localhost:19080/jpa2/Employee.svc/ALERTSs?$filter=OPERATOR eq 'a'
```

but this gives me following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.uri.expression.FilterParserImpl
```

Can somebody help me in resolving this error?

Comment: Are you sure the olingo lib is on your classpath?

Comment: Yeah Jean, I am....I am Using following jars:- olingo-odata2-api-annotation-incubating-1.0.0, olingo-odata2-api-incubating-1.0.0, olingo-odata2-core-incubating-1.0.0 , olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api-incubating-1.0.0 ,olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core-incubating-1.0.0.

Comment: Just a guess: The versions of odata and olingo do not match. Maybe you also have a version of the odata lib somewhere that has a different version?

Comment: Jean, that might be but the jars I wrote are the only options seem to me.Could you check if I can add more jars apart from these listed ones? Or there is something else that I can do about this?

Comment: No I can't check that. I don't know anything about odata nor olingo. Maybe you can just try different versions of the jars you have right now. Or manage to find the others jars that you have not added yourself.